# Using items in submodules from `extern crate` in root module

Tags: rust, rust-crates

My understanding is that `extern crate foo;` declarations in the root module are then importable in any submodule with `use foo::bar`. While this works in one submodule, it doesn't work in the other submodule. Any ideas why this might not work?

```
|--- main.rs
|--- module1
     |--- mod.rs
     |--- submod1.rs
|--- module2
     |--- mod.rs
     |--- submod2.rs

// main.rs
extern crate rustc_serialize;
mod module1;
mod module2;

// module1/mod.rs
mod submod1;

// module1/submod1.rs
use rustc_serialize::json; // WORKS

// module2/mod.rs
mod submod2;

// module2/submod2.rs
use rustc_serialize::json; // DOESN'T WORK
```

EDIT: I forgot that in my project, `module1` is defined as a library crate, which detached it from the usual import namespaces

Comment: Your example works for me with `rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)`. I did have to add an empty `main` method to main.rs.

Comment: Hm you're right it does work... it doesn't work in the actual code though. There are `extern crate` statements in `module1/mod.rs`, though, does that affect it?

Comment: Yes. This question is probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27653198/155423 then.

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out. I defined `module1/mod.rs` to be a library crate in order to generate documentation